# Faceting on multiple collections is slow

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a very slow performance downgrade when using the same query for multiple collections.
query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?
q=[text]&
fq=((l_id:([some id]) AND l_departed:false))&
qf=field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6&
sort=field1 asc, id asc,&
rows=0&
indent=true&
facet=on&
facet.pivot=field1,field2,field3&
facet.missing=true&
facet.mincount=1
```

if I use the `collection` parameter with all collections it will be very slow, even though the collection schema is the same.
The difference is something like for one `collection` is 4ms and for all is 4000ms.

Can you help me understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that upgrading solr from version 7.2 to at least 8 fixes the performance issue, without doing anything to the query.